# Remote Attribute not allowing Post

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, asp.net-ajax

Have a painfully simple blog Post creator, and I'm trying to check if the name of the Post is in use already.  The Ajax is posting back correctly, but the page will not allow me to submit, and does not throw any errors.  If I set break points within the Create() action, they are never hit.

**The Model:**

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("CheckPostName","Home")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [StringLength(400)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

**The Ajax Action:**

```
public bool CheckPostName(string Name)
{
    bool result = db.Posts.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(Name)).Count() == 0;
    return result;
}
```

**The Submit Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Post thePost)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(thePost);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
        return View(thePost);
    }
```

**And the View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<fieldset>
    <legend>Post</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you return JSON from your AJAX controller action that is supposed to validate the data:

```
public ActionResult CheckPostName(string Name)
{
    bool result = db.Posts.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(Name)).Count() == 0;
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Remember: controller actions must always return an ActionResult, otherwise they are not controller actions.